# Nginx won't serve static files (Reverse Proxy + Express API)?

Tags: express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I cannot manage to get Nginx to serve my static files. It always gives me 302 errors. I have my static files in a public folder (`/home/user/Documents/myapp.com/CURRENT PROJECT/public`) and want to serve them when a user goes to the site and requests `myapp.com/css/style.css`, `myapp.com/js/main_script.js`... I have the permission but from what I can tell it either can't find the file or ignores it completely and tries to serve them from the API(I can't use express.static anymore).

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid

http {
    upstream loadbalance {
        least_conn;
        server myapp:8003;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.myapp.com;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;

        return 301 https://myapp.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        root "/home/user/Documents/myapp.com/CURRENT PROJECT/public";
        server_name myapp.com;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;

        # This would not work
        location /css/ {
                autoindex on;
        }

        # This would not work
        location ~ \.(css|js|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|mp3) {
                 root '/home/user/Documents/app.com/CURRENT PROJECT/public';
                 gzip_static on;
                 expires max;
        }

        #Api
        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://loadbalance;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up the reverse proxy, you should manage with express the routing of the static files.
My settings for the proxy:

```
location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to serve static files with Nginx because it is more efficient if it is handled before it reaches express. 
Also I didn't mention it because I didn't want to make it more complicated but I am using hyper-express based on uWebsockets not normal Express.

`My real issue is that Nginx won't serve files even if I want to straight up serve a static HMTL file.`